# How to convert mysql to SQLite using PHP

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I have a database on mysql server. I want to convert that to sqlite3 database without using shell or perl scripts. I want some help converting the same using PHP. Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the the database, you should easily create a mysql dump (in the form of SQL creates and inserts) and then run it in sqlite.
You'll probably need to change the table creation statements though, because of different column datatypes used by each engine.

Comment: Thank you again for your help.
i was doing some research on this subject and i find a code which allow me to this but i think there's some problem somewhere.
This is the link : http://blog.jembe.fr/convertir-mysql-en-sqlite-en-php/