# How can I convert MySQL database to SQLite in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite

I need PHP code to convert the database. I tried [How to convert mysql to SQLite using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226067/how-to-convert-mysql-to-sqlite-using-php) but it dint have answer

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060029/how-to-convert-mysql-to-sqlite3-using-php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally found its solution.
Save sh file available at
https://gist.github.com/943776
and execute
"`./mysql2sqlite.sh  DBNAME --databases DBNAME -u DB_USERNAME -pDB_PASSWORD | sqlite3 database.sqlite`"(without qoutes and with "`")
in php file.
Save both files in one folder

Answer (score 4):

Go to phpmyadmin
click export database
download as sql file.

Download it....

go to your sql lite management software
import the .sql file

done...

Comment: If you do not have access to PhpMyAdmin, you could use the mysql dump command and use this file to import it into your sqlite database.

Comment: I need to do it using PHP script. Basically I need to get all the SQL queries of SQLite.

Comment: Hi Michael!
I want to do all these things via PHP code. Let me explain my requirements. I have to write a PHP code which dumps MYSQL database into SQLite. Can you help me in it?

Comment: Uhm, simple? Do the mysql dump, save it to file, download the file, then write a new php file to which takes an input file, processes into the sql lite database...

Comment: You still did not get my query. I want a PHP code to generate .sqlite file from a MYSQL database

Comment: And if it isn't clear... **write it yourself** All you need is to do the sql dump and upload it in your database. The sql is practically the same.
Read up on sql, php and experiment. We don't write code for you. We point you in the right direction, if you provide code, we correct errors, find errors, help you solve problems, but what we do not do is write it from scratch for you.
How ever, if you're willing to pay my professional fee per hour, i'm willing to do it for you.

Comment: I did not ask you to do the coding for me. All I wanted was a bit more help as I am new in PHP. Anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: No go! SQLite3 is not compatible with MySQL create statements.